# Gazebo plugin intro tutorial

Tags: ros, gazebo, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i'm trying to do this [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro) about Gazebo plugin intro, but when run `rosmake`  i get the next error

```
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['gazebo_tutorials']                                  
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130312-103713    
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['gazebo_tutorials'] to:
['gazebo_tutorials']                   
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages gazebo_tutorials.  This may take a few seconds.
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_tutorials [ make ]                                        
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lineszebo_tutorials: 7.5 sec ]               [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 
  [rosbuild] Building package gazebo_tutorials
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build
  cd build && make -l2
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_tutorials
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gazebo_tutorials.dir/src/simple_world_plugin.o
  /home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:1:21: fatal error: gazebo.hh: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/gazebo_tutorials.dir/src/simple_world_plugin.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gazebo_tutorials.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/moni/fuerte_workspace/gazebo_tutorials/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package gazebo_tutorials written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130312-103713/gazebo_tutorials/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_tutorials [FAIL] [ 7.64 seconds ]                         
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package gazebo_tutorials. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 failures.                                             
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                   
[ rosmake ] /home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130312-103713
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57894/gazebo-plugin-intro-tutorial/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial you mention says it is for ROS Fuerte, but you seem to be running Electric.

I would not expect that to work, because Fuerte introduced gazebo-1.0, a significant change from the previous versions.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1